# How to check if PFQuery result is true in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfuser

In my application, users can select three different account types at sign up: Parent User, Family Account, and Child Account. I added a column in the users database in Parse called "isParent" and set it as a boolean. Now, in the AppDelegate, I want to check if "isParent" is true, so I can display a certain ViewController. I have the following code:

In AppDelegate.swift within didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
    if PFUser.currentUser() == nil {
      // code to show sign up/login goes here

        }

    } else {

        let query = PFUser.query()
        query?.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)

        if query["isParent"] == true{   // error here. see below.
           // parent view controller
              print("this user is a parent")

            }
        } else{
            // non parent view controller
            print("this user is not parent")

        }
    }
```

As you read above, the error is within:

```
if query["isParent"] == true{
```

I get the following error message:

> Type "PFQuery?" has no subscript members

So, I want to be able to check if "isParent" is true so I can open a view controller.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fire the query to get data and after that you can check your condition.

You can user PFQuery class's method to get data.

```
findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock
findObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget:selector:
getFirstObject 
getFirstObjectInBackground ....etc.
```

You can choose your method...